# how can I implement adding "+1" step when calculating two's complement for a negative number

Tags: c++, string, twos-complement

The program works fine for unsigned integers for any given Length but for negative integers, if the integer is -99 and length is 8 then the output is 10011100 however correct answer is 10011101. so, basically, the "+1" step is missing. How can I code it without adding a new library or using arrays?

$

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// DONT MAKE ANY ADDITION
// DONT USE ANY ARRAY DATA TYPE

string decimalToTwoComplimentString(int a, int length)
{
    int bitSize=0;
    string binary, r_bin;

    for(int j=abs(a); j>=0; j/=2)
    {
        if(a>=0) // NO PROBLEM HERE
        {
            if(bitSize!=length)
            {
                if(j%2==0)
                    binary.append("0");
                else if(j%2==1)
                    binary.append("1");
                bitSize++;
            }
            else if(bitSize==length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        else if(a<0) // ADDING +1 AT THE END PART IS MISSING!
        {
            if(bitSize!=length)
            {
                if(j%2==0)
                    binary.append("1");
                else if(j%2==1)
                    binary.append("0");
                bitSize++;
            }
            else if(bitSize==length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=binary.length()-1; i>=0; i--) // PRINTING STRING BACKWARDS
    {
        r_bin+=binary.at(i);
    }
    return r_bin;
}

int main()
{
    int L;
    cout<< "Enter bit pattern size";
    cin>>L;

    int a, b;
    cout<<"Enter an integer a ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter an integer b ";
    cin>>b;

    int c1 = a + b;
    cout<<"In decimal "<< a << " + " << b << " is " << c1 << endl;

    string A = decimalToTwoComplimentString(a, L);
    string B = decimalToTwoComplimentString(b, L);

    cout<< "The Two's complement of " << a << " is \t" << A << endl;
    cout<< "The Two's complement of " << b << " is \t" << B << endl;


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and why can't you figure it out? Just treat the result as an unsigned integer and add 1. Nobody said you have to put everything in a single big loop. There are some weird logic in your code though, such as checking if the number is negative inside the loop instead of outside, which causes the check to happen every single iteration instead of just during the start.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem here. Two's complement (not *compliment*) addition and subtraction are exactly the same as the unsigned versions, so no separate adders are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to convert to a string by constantly dividing by 2 and checking if you have an even or odd value, you should simply use bitwise operations. If you did that, you wouldn't need to differentiate between negative and positive values because you'd just be looking at a single bit at a time. You could achieve the same thing by using the shift right operator, `>>` and a bit mask to get the least significant bit. Something like this:

```
string decimalToTwoComplimentString(int a, int length)
{
    string binary;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (a & 0x01)
        {
            binary.append("1");
        }
        else
        {
            binary.append("0");
        }
        a = a >> 1;
    }

    // ... and then reverse it
}
```

So what's happening here is that we're operating on the bits of the input value `a`. The logical AND operator (`&`) takes 2 values and does a bitwise AND of them. What that means is that it takes bit 0 from the left operand and bit 0 from the right operand and asks if they are both equal to 1. If so, the result is 1, otherwise the result is 0. Then it does the same thing for bit 1, then bit 2, etc. When you have `a & 0x01`, then the first operand is `a`, and the second operand is the hex value 01, which is just 1. So only bit 0 is set. The other 32 bits are 0. That means that `&` will return 0 for bits 1-31. But for bit 0, the result will be whatever `a` has in bit 0.

The `>>` operator, then moves all the bits 1 to the right. The lowest bit falls off the end and is never heard from again. We do the same thing again until we reach the 32nd bit.

Comment: He can also skip the entire "reverse it" loop if he just prepends to the string instead of appends.  That is: `binary = std::string((a&1) ? "1":"0") + binary;`

Comment: could you briefly explain the (a & 0x01) part whats the purpose of "0x01"?

Comment: Good point! I've added an explanation. Let me know if it makes sense.